# How to run shell script in linux agent of a TFS server

Tags: linux, git, tfs, agent

I not able to understand these below errors, can someone point out why am i getting these errors, when try run shell script which is in github `error: pathspec 'refs/remotes/origin/master' did not match any file(s) known to git Git checkout failed with exit code: 1`.

```
******************************************************************************
Starting: Build
******************************************************************************


Current agent version: '2.105.7'
******************************************************************************


Starting: Get Sources
******************************************************************************


Syncing repository: Job (TfsGit)


git version

git config --get remote.origin.url

git config gc.auto 0

git config --get-all

http.http://54.183.83.168:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_git/Job.extraheader

git config --get-all http.proxy

git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer ********" fetch --tags --prune --progress origin

git checkout --progress --force refs/remotes/origin/master

error: pathspec 'refs/remotes/origin/master' did not match any file(s) known to git

Git checkout failed with exit code: 1


******************************************************************************
Finishing: Get Sources
*****************************************************************************

*

*****************************************************************************

*

Starting: Post Job Cleanup
******************************************************************************

Cleaning any cached credential from repository: Job (Git)

git remote set-url origin 

http://54.183.83.168:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_git/Job

git remote set-url --push origin 

http://54.183.83.168:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_git/Job
******************************************************************************
Finishing: Post Job Cleanup
******************************************************************************
******************************************************************************
Finishing: Build
******************************************************************************
```

Comment: i not able to understand these below errors, can someone point out why am i getting these errors, when try run shell script which is in github                                                                            "error: pathspec 'refs/remotes/origin/master' did not match any file(s) known to git

Git checkout failed with exit code: 1"

Comment: I've added your comment to the question body, it'll be clearer for potential answerers I guess.

Comment: Please share your build definiton - Get Sourcs phase.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to clone an empty git repository.

I have the same error:
[image]

Initialize your repository or select another
[image]

and you`ll get your files.
[image]

Comment: yeh, i finally figure out, that i had to add my github repo with my crendentials as an endpoint in tfs under services tab/section (i still wonder whether it is absolutely necessary or not) and also i had to clone that repo in my linux machine agent, provide that path in shell-script path field and then pass my script specific parameters in "Arguments" field, with all this added, my script got executed successfully

Answer (score 0):

yeh, i finally figure out, that i had to add my github repo with my crendentials as an endpoint in tfs under services tab/section (i still wonder whether it is absolutely necessary or not) and also i had to clone that repo in my linux machine agent, provide that path in shell-script path field and then pass my script specific parameters in "Arguments" field, with all this added, my script got executed successfully